`I am trying to build a registration form in Django, using Django form
i put {{form.username}} {{ form.email }} {{ form.password }} in my html code instead of text boxes and i can't see them, i also made a forms.py file and views.py
this is register.html
`{% load static %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>User Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%  static "register.css" %}">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>User Registration</h2>
        <form action="" method="post">
            {%  csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
            {{form.username}}
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
            {{ form.email }}
            </div>
            
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
           
             {{ form.password }}
            </div>
           
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Register</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`

this is forms.py
`from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =[ 'username', 'email', 'password']`


this is views.py
`def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'register.html')`

I tried debugging, wathing a tutorial and asking chat gpt and i couldn't fix it

You never include it in the context of your call to render

probably render(request, 'register.html', {"form": form})

now for some reason it only shows the username but not the email and password... ( i used tje rennder with { form: ...
